# Highstock - Get two data from database using JSON and display into a Chart using addseries

Tags: getjson, highcharts

I'm trying to use Highstock to display a chart like in this example. [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume/)

I need to use two `JSON` code because i want to display two data from different table in my database.
The first data is OHLC and volume. OHLC and volume are displayed in different `yAxis` just like the example above.

The second data is High and Low Forecast and i want to display it together with OHLC in the same `yAxis`. While volume is remain the same (displayed in different `yAxis` from OHLC and Forecast).

Here is the code i tried so far, but it only display OHLC and Volume. Somehow, the Forecast data is not added. I think the `addSeries()` is the problem. Could anyone help me please?

Thank you.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var ohlc = [];
    var volume = [];
    var dataLength = data.length;

    for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
        ohlc.push([
            data[i][0], // the date
            data[i][1],
            data[i][2],
            data[i][3],
            data[i][4] // open
        ]);

        volume.push([
            data[i][0], // the date
            data[i][5] // the volume
        ])
    }

    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 0,
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Historical'
        },

        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: 'OHLC'
            },
            height: 200,
            lineWidth: 2
        }, {
            title: {
                text: 'Volume'
            },
            top: 300,
            height: 100,
            offset: 0,
            lineWidth: 2
        }],

        series: [{
            type: 'candlestick',
            name: 'AAPL',
            data: ohlc,
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Volume',
            data: volume,
            yAxis: 1,
        }]
    });
});

$.getJSON(urlprediction, function(data) {
    var forecast = [];
    var dataLength = data.length;

    for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
        forecast.push([
            data[i][0], // the date
            data[i][1],
            data[i][2], // open
        ])
    }

    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.addSeries({
        type: 'arearange',
        name: 'ADBE',
        data: forecast,
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In case when you get data by JSON secondly, you should not use var chart = $('#container').highcharts(); . I advice to use this construction:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
var ohlc = [];
var volume = [];
var dataLength = data.length;

for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
    ohlc.push([
        data[i][0], // the date
        data[i][1],
        data[i][2],
        data[i][3],
        data[i][4] // open
    ]);

    volume.push([
        data[i][0], // the date
        data[i][5] // the volume
    ])
}

var chart = $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 0,
    },

    title: {
        text: 'AAPL Historical'
    },

    yAxis: [{
        title: {
            text: 'OHLC'
        },
        height: 200,
        lineWidth: 2
    }, {
        title: {
            text: 'Volume'
        },
        top: 300,
        height: 100,
        offset: 0,
        lineWidth: 2
    }],

    series: [{
        type: 'candlestick',
        name: 'AAPL',
        data: ohlc,
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Volume',
        data: volume,
        yAxis: 1,
    }]
},function(chart){
$.getJSON(urlprediction, function(data) {
    var forecast = [];
    var dataLength = data.length;

    for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
        forecast.push([
        data[i][0], // the date
        data[i][1],
        data[i][2], // open
        ])
    }

    chart.addSeries({
        type: 'arearange',
        name: 'ADBE',
        data: forecast,
    });
    });

});
```

});

Comment: It doesn't work. It give me blank page. The chart doesn't show up.

Comment: Hey Sebastian Bochan, I have found the answer. Now i have another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830101/highstock-issue-cant-draw-and-plot-chart-correctly). Could you help me please? Thank you.