# Highstock Issue - Can't draw and plot chart correctly

Tags: highcharts

I'm working on project to display stock information using `Highstock`.

**Question 1:**

I tried to display ohlc data using `ohlc` graph, high and low using `areasplinerange` graph, and volume using `column` chart.

Everything works fine, if i zoom `1m`, `3m`, `6m`, `YTD`, and `1y`. Here is the snapshot. [link1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlJgY.jpg). But if zoom to `All`, The graph messed up like this [link2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4KL0.jpg).

Am i wrong in my coding or it's bug?

**Question 2:**

In the same chart, I have code to change the type of graph from `ohlc` to `line`. It works fine when I zoom to `1m`, `3m`. Here is the snapshot [link3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHKb2.jpg). But it show me no line chart when i zoom to `6m`, `1y`, and `All`. Here is the snapshot [link4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BeR0.jpg).

How can this happen?

Thank you for your help.

**The Code:**
Here is the code that i used to display the chart

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data1) {
    $.getJSON(urlprediction, function (data2) {
        var ohlc = [],
            volume = [],
            closed = [],
            forecast = [],
            dataLength1 = data1.length;
            dataLength2 = data2.length;

        for (i = 0; i < dataLength1; i++) {
            ohlc.push([
                data1[i][0], // the date
                data1[i][1], // open
                data1[i][2], // high
                data1[i][3], // low
                data1[i][4] // close
            ]);

            closed.push([
                data1[i][0], // the date
                data1[i][4] // close
            ]);

            volume.push([
                data1[i][0], // the date
                data1[i][5] // the volume
            ])
        }

        for (i = 0; i < dataLength2; i++) {         
            forecast.push([
                data1[i][0], // the date
                data1[i][1],
                data1[i][2], // close
            ])
        }

        // set the allowed units for data grouping
        var groupingUnits = [[
            'week',                         // unit name
            [1]                             // allowed multiples
        ], [
            'month',
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
        ]];

        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

                rangeSelector: {
                    selected: 1
                },
                title: {
                    text: title
                },  
                yAxis: [{
                    title: {
                        text: 'OHLC'
                    },
                    height: 360,
                    lineWidth: 2
                }, {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Volume'
                    },
                    top: 433,
                    height: 100,
                    offset: 0,
                    lineWidth: 2
                }],
                series: [{
                    type: 'ohlc',
                    name: stockname,
                    data: ohlc,
                }, {
                    type: 'areasplinerange',
                    name: stockname,
                    data: data2,
                }, {
                    type: 'column',
                    name: 'Volume',
                    data: volume,
                    yAxis: 1,
                }]
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you recreate issue on jsFiddle? I think it is caused somehow by data you pass to Highcharts. Maybe series has different interval? Regarding issue with invisible series - you  can try master version: http://github.highcharts.com/master/highstock.js

Comment: The master version can't fix the problem. here is jsFiddle that you want. Thank you. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MJeFC/)